# How to get the html content from react-draft-wysiwyg from the child component to the parent?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get the html content that I've typed in the editor from the editor component (child) to the parent so I can save the form together with the editor's content into my database.

I've tried sending the getContent function into the Editor (child) as a prop and get back the content from the Editor but I keep getting the error showing that `getContent is not a function`.

What is the correct way to do this so I can get the html content from the Editor to the parent component?

[image]

**Editor.js (child)**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import { EditorState, convertToRaw } from 'draft-js';
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html';
import 'react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';
import './RichTextEditor.css';

const Editor = (getContent) => {
    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() =>
        EditorState.createEmpty()
    );

    const handleEditorChange = (state) => {
        setEditorState(state);
        sendContent();
    };

    const sendContent = () => {
        getContent(draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent())));
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Editor
                editorState={editorState}
                onEditorStateChange={handleEditorChange}
                wrapperClassName="wrapper-class"
                editorClassName="editor-class"
                toolbarClassName="toolbar-class"
            />
            <textarea value={draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))}></textarea>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Editor;
```

**CreateBulletin (parent)**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Editor from '../Editor/Editor'

const AddBulletin = () => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState ('')
    const [htmlContent, setHtmlContent] = useState('')

    const getContent = (htmlContentProp) => {
        setHtmlContent(htmlContentProp);
        console.log(htmlContentProp);
    }

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!title) {
            alert('Please add a title')
            return
        }

        onAdd({ title, htmlContent })

        setTitle('')
        setHtmlContent('')
    }

    return (
        <Row>
            <Col xs={12} md={8}>
                <form className='add-form' onSubmit={ onSubmit}>
                    <div className='form-control bulletin'>
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Insert your title here...' style={{width: '100%'}}
                        value={title} onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
                    </div>
                    <div className='form-control bulletin'>
                        <label>Content</label>
                        <Editor getContent={getContent} />
                    </div>
                    <Button as="input" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    <Button variant="outline-danger">Cancel</Button>
                </form>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    )
}

export default AddBulletin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A component props is always an object. Whatever props you receive will be a property of `props` object.

You can use like this

```
const Editor = (props) => {
... 
   props.getContent(...);
...
```

or

```
const Editor = ({getContent}) => {
... 
   getContent(...);
...
```

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you! I've actually missed out the curly braces for my getContent in the child component, that's why it wouldn't work.